# pip is not recognized as an internal or external command in windows7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have added the below lines in the path variable on my Windows 7 machine:

```
C:\Users\sample\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32;
C:\Users\sample\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages;
C:\Users\sample\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts
```

But still it shows

> pip is not recognized as an internal or external command

Thanks,
Dhinesh

Comment: Does `pip3` work?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into an issue with an installation where only running the pip module as a python script in command line worked. `pip install [pkg]` would fail but the following worked.

```
python -m pip install [pkg]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall Python completely.
2. Reinstall using the "[executable installer](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-361/)".
3. Tick the box to add Python to your path variable.
4. Restart computer (just in case).
5. Don't do anything else manually.
6. Run `pip`.

Comment: It's Python 3.6; shouldn't it be `pip3`?

Comment: `pip` is how you run it. If you have Python 2 and 3 installed, `pip` starts whatever is set as the default version for your computer. If you want to target a specific version, use `pip3` or even more specifically `pip3.5` or `pip3.6`.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have issues after trying [Exprator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7925166/exprator)'s solution, try adding PIP to Path variable

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem so I tried using - **py -m pip install [pkg]**
and it worked